# How to send multiple Soap call at the same time using php

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to send more than one soap API requests using php. I don't have any idea about that part can you please help me for this issue

How to send a multiple requests at the same time using php

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate multi-threading functionality into your application to perform the simultaneous operations try with this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.threaded.php)